# What happens between componentWillMount and componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using a global variable to setState in componentDidMount. But the value of the global variable is emptying itself.

Code:

```
componentWillMount () {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(global.variable)) //The value of the variable is intact
}

componentDidMount () {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(global.variable)) //The value of the variable is empty
    mqttFunction() {
       ...
       // telemetry updates and redux store actions
    }
}
```

what is happening here? Have I missed something here?

Comment: Where does your `global.variable` comes from ?

Comment: I am declaring that global variable in the previous screen and adding values to it.

Comment: Have you considered using Context api instead ? Then you save your `global.variable` into the context and pass your `global.variable` as `props` to your component

Comment: I'll try that. No I didn't consider it.